# Any way to mention Github Python packages or projects frequently used in questions and answers here?

Tags: discussion

Is there any way to mention to other users here Python packages or projects frequently referenced in questions and answers in this site?

Just for example https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield tag: [skyfield](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyfield) is used to precisely calculate the positions and velocities of planets and Earth satellites.

Mentioning wouldn't be limited to this site. A wiki answer or comment could do it.

Answer (score 3):

Seems reasonable to me--I'd put it in the tag wiki, not the excerpt. Maybe also worth adding to our software resources list!

Comment: oh, this! [Software tools for space exploration available online](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/790/12102)

Comment: @uhoh Yes, that's the one!